# Using .Split to Split a string and return first integer values

Tags: c#

Been trying to take a string and split it using a space and get the first integer from the string.  The integer has to be on its own, so no other characters in it. Any help appreciated

Comment: Could you add code that you have tried?

Comment: What are the assumptions on the input string?  You can use regular expressions though

Comment: Question is slightly ambiguous. If the string is like "63.87 abc", do you expect `6` or `63` or `87` or nothing?

Comment: If the string was 63.87 abc and it was split using "." I would want 63 returned.

Comment: 'and it was split using "."' - your question doesn't say anything about splitting on a specific (potentially variable) character like `.` - please [update your post with all relevant details](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69736606/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try *Linq* in order to query the `source` string:

```
 string source = "abc a5 123 789 pqr";

 string result = source
   .Split(' ')
   .FirstOrDefault(item => item.Any() && item.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9'));
```

Here we split `source` into

```
 {"abc", "a5", "123", "789", "pqr"}
```

and then get `"123"` - first *not empty* `item` which contains *digits only*.

**Edit:** Note, that, `result` is of type `string`, since not any sequence of digits is a valid `int`: e.g. `123456789123456789` is *too long* for `int`. If we can *guarantee* that `result` is short enough, then you can parse it into some itenteger type, e.g.

```
int answer = int.Parse(result);
```

or

```
long answer = long.Parse(result);
```

or even

```
BigInteger answer = BigInteger.Parse(result);
```

If we accept *negative* values as well, we can put *regular expression*:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string result = source
  .Split(' ')
  .FirstOrDefault(item => Regex.IsMatch(item, @"^\-?[0-9]+$"));
```

Comment: This seems to be working, when trying to return however it can't convert string to int, but I do want it to return as a string

Comment: Works!! Just wondered however what if the number is negative? tried to and returned value cannot be null.

Comment: @Nightz: Have you at least looked at [the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69736706/284240) which already supported negative integers and didn't need regex or other string methods(apart from `String.Split`)?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe

```
string input = "sdf fg gfh 4v 345gg g 4 dfg dfg";

int? result  = input.Split(' ')
   .Select(x => int.TryParse(x, out int val) ? val : (int?)null)
   .FirstOrDefault(x => x != null);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Output**

```
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var firstOrDefaultInteger = input.Split(' ')
    .FirstOrDefault(x => int.TryParse(x, out _));
```

Comment: When trying to return it can't convert string to int, I want it to return a string preferably

Comment: @Nightz It does return string.